# Why is my hover css being removed by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I was wanting to have an on hover feature in combination with a currently selected item feature for navigation. The hover feature is there when the page first loads; however, after selecting an item (and running the script), the hover css seems to have been removed and I'm not sure why. Here is my file ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BxPW3/)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
      <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
      <![endif]-->
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <title>TITLE</title>
      <style>
         ul {
            list-style: none;
         }

         li {
            background-color: orange;
            color: white;
            float: left;
            padding: 10px;
         }

         li:hover {
            background-color: grey;
            color: black;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <ul>
         <li>one</li>
         <li>two</li>
         <li>three</li>
         <li>four</li>
         <li>five</li>
      </ul>

      <script type="text/javascript">
         $("li").click(function() {
            $("li").each(function() {
               $(this).css({'background-color' : 'orange',      
                            'color' : 'white'});      
            });
            setHighlighted(this);
         });

         var setHighlighted = function(ref) {
            $(ref).css({'background-color' : 'grey',
                        'color' : 'black'
            });
         }
</script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't have the energy to write up a full answer, but use classes and save yourself a lot of headaches while getting much cleaner, saner code. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BxPW3/7/

Comment: Just a style note: it would be better and cleaner to simply add a *class* with JQuery and have the class style declaration in your CSS, rather than setting the CSS style *directly* using JQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are assigning the style property of the `li`'s with jQuery

```
$("li").each(function () {
    $(this).css({
        'background-color': 'orange',
            'color': 'white'
    });
});
```

This writes to the style tag of the element which supersedes the

```
 li:hover {
     background-color: grey;
     color: black;
 }
```

style

change your code to

```
$("li").click(function () {
    $("li").each(function () {
        $(this).css({
            'background-color': '',
                'color': ''
        });
    });
    setHighlighted(this);
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BxPW3/3/)

This will remove the `background-color` and `color` from the style property of the `li` elements which will make the `li:hover` the style that takes precedence

Answer (score 0):

Just add `!important` on li:hover selector for background-color.

```
li:hover {
            background-color: grey !important;
            color: black;
         }
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BxPW3/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Check the JS fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/BxPW3/4/

```
$("li").click(function() {
               /* $("li").each(function() {*/
                    $(this).css({
                        'background-color': 'orange',
                            'color': 'white'
                    });
              /*  });*/
                setHighlighted(this);
            });

            var setHighlighted = function(ref) {
                $(ref).css({
                    'background-color': 'grey',
                        'color': 'black'
                });
            }
```

Comment: Does not work the links will stay highlighted when another link is selected

Comment: have u checked the fiddle before commenting?

Comment: Yes i have and it is not working as it would be expected to. At any one time only one item should be selected.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do, and lighter :

```
$("li").each(function () {
    $(this).click(function () {
       //Your function
    });
});
```

Now, to set an "active" statment, you should add a class :

```
.markup{ 
    background-color: grey;
    color: black;  
}
```

And set this class to the right LI after removing the existing active LI :

```
$("li").each(function () {
    $(this).click(function () {
        $(".markup").removeClass("markup")
        $(this).addClass("markup");
    });
});
```

Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hEAAq/)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is much simpler :

```
li {
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    background-color: orange;
    color: white;
}

li:hover,
li.on {
    background-color: gray;
    color: black;
}
```

Plus, it leaves styling to CSS only :

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li', function(ev) {
    $(ev.delegateTarget).find('.on').removeClass('on');
    $(this).addClass('on');
});
```

See this fiddle : [jsfiddle.net/rG4a5/](http://jsfiddle.net/rG4a5/)

Comment: Oops ! duplicate. Didn't see @EdenSource's answer. Sorry.